# Looking for some lecture videos on logic, models of computation and computational complexity/tcs fundamentals

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, machine-models, first-order-logic

Looking for some lecture videos (introductory level) on  logic, models of computation as well as computational complexity/ other theoretical computer science fundamentals

Answer (score 6):

Ryan O'Donnell (professor at Carnegie Mellon) has a wonderful [undergraduate complexity theory series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxhpiYKFQd8&list=PLm3J0oaFux3YL5vLXpzOyJiLtqLp6dCW2) that goes through the fundamentals quite well, and he's an engaging lecturer. He also has a similar [graduate lecture series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRnnEOAQZF8&list=PLm3J0oaFux3b8Gg1DdaJOzYNsaXYLAOKH) that mostly picks up where the undergrad series left off.

(Note that this series does not cover logic, and I'm not aware of any videos that do cover that subject.)

Answer (score 3):

Prof. Tim Roughgarden (Stanford University) Lectures on algorithms and more are also great. He is one of the best lecturers out there...

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcH4Ga14Y4ELFKrEYM1vXCg/playlists